# Initializing a std::string with function return value, is there a copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, swap

I have the following code, I am using GCC and C++11:

```
std::string system_call(const char *cmd){
   std::string a;
   ...
   return a;
}

std::string st = system_call("whatever code");
```

Is there an implicit copy there?
I am calling this function many times, and I guess it is doing a copy from the return value of the `system_call` to the variable `st`, and later on releasing the temporary r-value.

Is there any way I can avoid the copy? Using `st.swap(system_call())` throws and error in the compiler:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   'std::basic_string::swap(std::string)'

My questions are:

1. If there is a problem or not
2. How to avoid it, if there is one

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Found a way to make the explicit swap work. But the answers where right, there is no benefit since the compiler was already replacing st with the return value, without any copy.

```
system_call("whatever").swap(st);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, if the `std::string` is constructed in the call and then returned most modern compilers with apply the return value optimization (a special case of [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)). Your case in particular is the Named RVO (thanks @NathanOliver for pointing this out), if you want to look up the precise rules. From C++17 on this optimization is guaranteed through the standard.

Whether or not the optimization is applied is hard to tell, however if it is not, then in C++11 and above it is very likely that the `std::string` object in the scope of the function will be moved from and that the return value will be moved to. You could theoretically call `std::move` on the return value, but thereby you would also prevent any RVO from happening. While move may be efficient, RVO typically yields faster code, because nothing is moved or copied at all, but the object is constructed in place, so I would advise against doing it, and in favor of relying on your compiler.

Comment: It is good to know that compiler might already be doing it. But is it there any way I can force it do it? Swap doesn't seem to work since it needs a non-temporary reference.

Comment: You could call `std::move` on the return value, but that would prevent copy elision by the rules of the standard, which is still more efficient than moving. If the small string optimization is applied moving from a string may e.g. be not that much more efficient, if at all. I would advise against call move. Also where do you want to call swap? Personal estimate is that returning by value and relying on the RVO is going to yield the most performant solution here.

Comment: @DarkZeros There  is no way to force the compiler not to implement `a += b` as `a = 0; for (int i = 0; i < b;++i) ++a;`  At some point you do have to presume a non-malicious compiler.  Elision of return values is a universal C++ compiler feature nowadays.  So long as you `return named_variable;` directly, or `return temporary;` directly, and the types match, either elision (if possible) or moving (if not) will occur.  Between `system_call` and `st` elision is guaranteed *in practice* barring pathological compiler flags.

Comment: specifically this is NRVO which is a little harder to optimize.

Comment: @DarkZeros when we are worried about the compiler doing something odd or foolish, we'd instruct the compiler to keep the intermediary files and give them a read. If we found unwanted behaviour we'd go back and tweak the code to avoid it. Or sometimes you just live with it because the cost of the fix exceeds the benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Elision is the permission the standard gives to compilers to make multiple values share existence, when they seem to be different values in the code.

```
std::string system_call(const char *cmd){
  std::string a;
  ...
  return a; // all return paths return `a` directly
}

std::string st = system_call("whatever code");
```

In the above case, elision means that `a`, the return value of `system_call` and `st` are all *the same object*.

Modern compilers elide unless you give them a pathological flag to say "don't elide", whenever the standard and the code permits it.  "What if it doesn't elide when possible" is like asking what if the compiler implements integer addition as a looped increment.

Both are permitted by the standard, neither are reasonable to expect.

When elision fails (because your code makes it impossible), it falls back on move semantics in C++11.  For `std::string` that means no memory allocation occurs on the move; in the case of a small string optimization some small number of characters may be copied.

Elision can fail if your code could return a given named variable along one path, and a different one or a temporary along another path.  Or if you return a function parameter.

Elision is permitted if your return statement is `return named_variable;` or `return some_temporary_object;`, where the returned object matches the type of the function return.  It is also permitted when you do `some_type bob = some_temporary;`, where `some_temporary` is a temporary object of type `some_type`.  Similarly you can elide into a function argument (but not out of it).

There is no way to "guarantee" elision.

C++17 makes almost all of the elide-from-temporary cases above mandatory.

For elision to work in C++14 and before, there must be a copy or move constructor.  When elision occurs, it is not called, but it must exist.  In C++17 when temporaries are "force" elided, no copy or move constructor need exist: the temporary is not a distinct object, but rather a clause that represents "how to construct an object", which is only done later.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is tagged as `c++11`, I assume you are compiling the code with a `c++11` compiler.

In this case, the value returned by `system_call` won't be copied. The compiler might move construct `st` with the return value, or use Return Value Optimization to erase the copy. Either way, there won't be a copy.

Comment: specifically this is NRVO which is a little harder to optimize.